# Why does the compiler suggest to use itself in the module?

Tags: rust

I have following module:

```rust
mod types {
    use std::str::FromStr;

    struct StringParseError;

    pub enum ProcStat {
        PSRunning,
    }

    impl FromStr for ProcStat {
        type Err = StringParseError;

        fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
            match s {
                "R" => Ok(PSRunning),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While building, I got:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `PSRunning` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:15:27
   |
15 |                 "R" => Ok(PSRunning),
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
help: possible candidate is found in another module, you can import it into scope
   |
2  |     use crate::types::ProcStat::PSRunning;
   |
```

What is the correct usage here? I may have missed this part in the documentation.

Comment: The compiler is slightly overzealous here. `PSRunning` is not defined as a free-standing identifier but only via its path `ProcStat::PSRunning`, since it's part of that enum. The line should therefor read `... => Ok(ProcStat::PSRunning)`. You can - since a few versions back - import enum members into the local scope, that's what the compiler is suggesting.

Comment: Ah, I thought this is about mod. Thanks.

Comment: And by "a few versions back", the previous commenter means since Rust 1.0.